# Curl doesn't accept my ssl key

Tags: ssl, curl

I am running the following command on unix using curl :

```
curl -v  -d @SampleRequest_OFFSHORE.xml -E ./mypemfile.pem:nopass --cacert ./ifind.prod.ClientAuth.abc.com.CER https://world-service-dev.intra.abc.com:4414/worldservice/CLIC/CaseManagementService/V1
```

I am getting the following error:

```
* About to connect() to world-service-dev.intra.abc.com port 4414 (#0)
```

*   Trying 148.171.176.115... connected
* Connected to world-service-dev.intra.abc.com (148.171.176.115) port 4414 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
*   CAfile: ./ifind.prod.ClientAuth.abc.com.CER
  CApath: none
* Unable to load client key -8178.
* NSS error -8178
* Closing connection #0
curl: (58) Unable to load client key -8178.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your keys are in the right keystore?
Did you try and change the file permissions on the keystore?

Comment: Yes the permissions are fine , the certs are in the same directory from where I am running the curl command .
`-rwxrwxrwx  1 igupt6 splkCIRPtrce1  1956 Feb 25 14:15 ifind.prod.ClientAuth.aexp.com.CER`
`rwxrwxrwx  1 igupt6 splkCIRPtrce1  4301 Feb 25 10:31 mypemfile.pem`

Comment: There are a bunch of results that show up if you Google for "Unable to load client key -8178." Maybe some of them will trigger some questions for you.